# Dual boot Manjaro and Windows without switching to AHCI

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, raid, mdadm, manjaro

I've recently bought a new Lenovo IdeaPad C340 with an M.2 SSD and Windows 10 preinstalled. Now I want to dual-boot it with Manjaro (Awesome WM edition, shouldn't matter through).

The problem: Neither the installer on the live USB, nor Gparted, nor even `ls /dev` does detect the SSD.

After some research I discovered that my SSD is operating with Intel RST. In order to switch to AHCI, I followed [this](https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci) instruction. It worked fine, but the Laptop feeled so dramaticaly slower after that, even after several reboot, I didn't even need a benchmark to tell there's something wrong with the SSD. The start time went from under 5sec to ~30sec. Futhermore, I was unable to turn the laptop off / reboot it, as the power light just continues to glow (for a long time) even when the screen went dark. Further searching revealed that this is a common problem when switching to AHCI, and the only option is to reinstall Windows. Great.

Afterwards I switched back to Intel RST (using same instructions), and now try to get the Manjaro Live USB to detect the said SSD, with no luck so far. When I look at the RST options in the UEFI, the SSD is a non-RAID PCIe NVM SSD. (Of course, I only have one drive, why the hell is that thing set to RST in the first place?)

There are many tutorial / references / information out there describing how to make a RAID0 or RAID1 with RST, or how to accompish what I want by switching to AHCI. But I don't need this. I just want Manjaro to detect this SSD.

Is there any way to accomplish this by for example configuring it with `mdadm`? Or is there any way one can fix that Windows issues without nuking and reinstalling it?

**Note:** USB-Boot is enabled, Secure Boot and Legacy Support disabled. Futhermore, `/dev/mapping/control` is present, but no further devices are in `/dev/mapping` and there are no `/dev/dm-*` devices neither. And I'm not 100% sure if the problem is really with RST.

Comment: _...why the hell is that thing set to RST in the first place?_ The IdeaPad C340 is not Linux-certified, so Some Genius  at Lenovo decided they wanted the system to run as fast as possible, without considering someone might want to put Linux on it.

Comment: If you can get your laptop back to normal, install VMware Workstation (or Hyper-V) and install the Linux system as a guest. I have done that here with Kali and with Ubuntu both

Comment: John, I will probably do some stuff which requires native performance, so virtualisation is not an option. Also, I do not want to rely on Windows beeing kind to me and working all the time.